# What is the difference between "As per" and "As for"?

Tags: expressions, differences, word-usage

What is the difference between "As per" and "As for"?
As for our professional services or as per our professional services?

Comment: It's not a hard-and-fast rule, but usually "as for" could almost be taken as another way of saying "with regard to..." and "as per" is pretty much the same as "in accordance with". In the context of professional services, the first would be talking about what the services are or do, while the second would be saying something will happen as usual for the service.

Answer (score 4):

**As For:** this could mean 'with regard to something' For example, *I've already agreed to go to France,* **as for** *Sarah, I'm not sure if she's going*.
This is on the topic of Sarah's choice as opposed to my choice of going to France.

**As Per:** this could mean 'according to or in accordance to' For example, *I've already agreed to go to France,* **as per** *Sarah, it's not advised to travel at this time of the year.*
According to the information I received from Sarah, travelling at this time is not advised.

*My teachers are very pleased with my exam results*, **as for** *my final project, they couldn't compliment it enough*

*My teachers are very pleased with my exam results*, **as per** *my final project, the school adopted the mobile app that made registering for classes easier.*

Answer (score 0):

*"As **per"*** is latin - where *per* means *for* - you may use in phrase ; however this kind of refinement needs a certain context & form of your speech. So I'd advise you to remain simple to prefer "as for our pro. services..."